# Example of Synecdoche?

Tags: literary-techniques, literary-device

I need some examples of synecdoche!! Can someone post a few examples of synecdoche? I found only these- "lend me your ears" and "the hand that mocked".

Comment: No! But thanks for sharing your unwillingness!

Comment: MPL has said it all.  :) The very simplest most obvious example is "sports team names" -- to copy and paste the example in the dictionary "England" "the English cricket team".

Comment: Regarding the two examples you mention - really, we should get other opinions but I believe those ARE NOT synecdohce!  They are just, uh, metaphors or something.

Comment: Of these two, I am quite sure. But yes, may be we should get more opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the essence of synecdoche is that a part of something stands for the whole intended thing, the most common examples involve body parts or pieces of clothing:

> Faint heart never won fair lady. [Or more precisely, a suitor with a faint heart never did.]
>
> To win the war, we'd need another 200,000 boots on the ground. [On the feet of 100,000 soldiers, logically—though current usage may apportion one boot per soldier.]
>
> The key to success online is to capture as many eyeballs as possible. [But only if they're attached in each instance to a head, torso, and wallet.]
>
> All hands on deck! [And the rest of each sailor, too.]

But in other instances they may also involve other appurtenances:

> The A's hope to add a couple of bats to the middle of their weak offensive lineup. [The hoped-for bats being distinguished from the bats held by players already in the lineup by the fact that they would be wielded by players who could actually hit well.]
>
> The deputy warned the sheriff that a young gun had arrived in town. [The gun may have been young or old, but it was being carried by a young gunfighter.]

Comment: Thanx.. Your answer was quite useful..